# force app orientation to landscape in code

Tags: firemonkey, c++builder, c++builder-10.3-rio

I'm building a multi-device application in C++ in Rad Studio Rio (10.3.2).  The primary target is an iPhone.  I'd like to have a button click that **forces** the app to landscape regardless of the phones actual orientation.

How can I do this?  I'm looking for something like this:

```
Form1->Orientation = Landscape;
```

I know I can force the app to be portrait or landscape at design time: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Application_Orientation but that is NOT what I want.  I want to do it in my code at run time.

I can write code to change forms at runtime (e.g. make a "portrait" version of my form and a "landscape" version of my form and switch between them) but I'm hoping there is a code solution to let me use my one form and force it into landscape when i want.

thanks,
russ

Comment: Is there any case you have access to the base iOS codebase?

Comment: Hi Harsh - I'm not sure what your asking.  I'm writing the code in Rad Studio (C++).  I'll update my post to make it clearer.

Comment: This seems possible in Delphi but not in C++ Builder?  [Screen orientation](https://community.idera.com/developer-tools/programming-languages/f/delphi-language/67640/screen-orientation-problem-with-tchart-in-delphi-10-3-rio)